# Floating div in Firefox goes to next line due to large content

Tags: firefox, html, newline, css-float

I've got to some unstandart situation, with html markup.
Currently using two floating divs

```
 .navigation 
 {
     width: 200px;
     float: left;
 }

 .content
 {
     float: left;
 }
```

the problem is that Firefox moves second div to next line, onle it's content is larger than page width -200px. How to resolve this issue to fit second div rest of page space without max-width property, because my content is displayed in differen res monitors from 1024 to 1980 px width.
Happens currently only in Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you’ve got a parent container you could give that `padding-left: 200px` and `.navigation { margin-left: -200px; }`. That way you could get rid of `float: left;` on content as it’ll always be padded in by the parent.

Comment: Voted, yeap, I know that hack, but want to make more clear solution, still using floating divs.